# How to warn user on Timecard Review page, OTL?

Tags: otl

User enters time on timecard page and clicks on ‘Continue’ button.
On the review page he does not ‘Submit’ or goes ‘Back’ or ‘Cancel’. But clicks on other links such as ‘Home’ or ‘Preferences’, etc.

Requirement is to provide a warning message to the user on the Time card review page when he does not save the timecard but navigates off the page. How it can be done?